# MDN <text> wrap if max length?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg

I have

```
<text>
very long text
</text>
```

I wish to limit the length of the text in pixels or percent of parent width, such that if the text in  reaches the limit then it will start a new line. The text is dynamically generated and not known until runtime.

Comment: the easier solution to your problem is using a [<foreignObject>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) so that you can include an HTML tag like `<p>`

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of creating my own methodology but was wondering if there was already an easier solution out there.